# Entered Text is removed from Date text field using Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to enter date in date text field using sendkeys, but as soon as focus moves from it text vanishes.
HTML ;

```
 <div class="v-datefield v-datefield-popupcalendar v-widget v-datefield-day">
<input id="gwt-uid-109" class="v-textfield v-datefield-textfield" type="text" aria-describedby="gwt-uid-105" aria-controls="gwt-uid-106" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-108" tabindex="0"/>
```

i have tried send keys getElement(locator).sendKeys(expectedValue);

Comment: Are you still facing the problem? Can you provide more of the HTML DOM?

Answer (score 0):

The field is programmed in a way that if you TAB out of the date field the value resets to ""

If I may suggest, Try it manually and see if it has the same behavior.
To over come this through sselenium: 
Try this: 
• First DatefieldElement.Clear();
• Then DateFielsElement.SendKeys(value)
• Then use Robot API to hit enter key

```
Robot rob = new Robot
Thread.sleep(500);
rob.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
```

Comment: Guess you should use the DatePicker then- @UmeshKumar